# gunicorn not starting workers

Tags: django, gunicorn

When i run this command

```
[jenia@arch app]../bin/gunicorn zones.wsgi:application --bind localht:8000
```

The gunicorn server runs at localhost:8000. It doesnt return anything to the console as I assume it should. Just runs silently.

When I run my script in `bin/gunicorn_start` the server still runs silently and features odd behaviour. If I input an address that django can't resolve it gives me `internal server error` and that's it. no stack trace no nothing.

This is the bin/gunicorn_start script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="hello_app" # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/srv/http/proj05/app # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/srv/http/proj05/app/run/gunicorn.sock # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=jenia # the user to run as
GROUP=jenia # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3 # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=zones.settings # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=zones.wsgi # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH


# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR



# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
echo "about to exec exec is" $DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
--name $NAME \
--workers $NUM_WORKERS \
--user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
--log-level=debug \
--bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

By the way, I created a virtualen at by doing:

```
cd proj05
virtualenv .
source bin/activate
pip install django
pip install gunicorn
...
```

Can anyone tell me how to make gunicorn output the debug information instead of just `internal server error`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oddly enough I'm having the exact same problem you are this morning.  Residual Friday 13th curse?

Comment: hehe. no there has been a new release on thursday.

Comment: btw, if you;re having the same problem, vote my question up plz.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by reverting back to Gunicorn 18.0.0.

```
pip uninstall gunicorn
pip install gunicorn==18.0.0
```

Not the ideal solution.  Perhaps it's worth making a bug ticket about this problem.  My concern is that I can't actually identify what the problem is...so how do I make a proper bug ticket?  haha

Answer (score 20):

gunicorn doesn't return to the console by default now. Use the option `--log-file=-` to do it.

Also the error should be fixed in https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/785 .

I will make a release tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `--log-file=-` option

For more information see: http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-i-don-t-see-any-logs-in-the-console